# cgo pointer value changed

Tags: pointers, go, bullet, cgo

I made bindings to a C api (bullet physics engine) using cgo, some functions make use of data pointers. The idea is that I can attach a pointer to an object and retrieve it later when the physics engine invokes a callback. My problem is that when i get the value back, it change and I didn't do it. It seems that no source code is explicitelly changing the value.

CollisionObject: [source](https://github.com/hydroflame/bullet282_with_better_c_api/blob/master/src/BulletCollision/CollisionDispatch/btCollisionObject.cpp), [header](https://github.com/hydroflame/bullet282_with_better_c_api/blob/master/src/BulletCollision/CollisionDispatch/btCollisionObject.h),
[The go codes that interracts with that class](https://github.com/hydroflame/gobullet/blob/master/rigidbody.go#L257)

heres how i **send** the values, the reconversion to *int and int is fine, the correct numbers are printed:

```
num := x*amounty*amountz + y*amountz + z + 1
ptr := unsafe.Pointer(&num)
fmt.Printf("created %v %v\n", ptr, *(*int)(ptr))
rb := sphere.RigidBody(ptr, 1)
```

But when I get it **back** from a raytest the value changed:

```
ptr := hit.GetUserPointer()
log.Printf("we got back: %v %v", ptr, *(*int)(ptr))
```

the pointer value itself didnt change, i can look up and see that there was a pointer pointing to this location, but the value its pointing at is different.

Now i'm wondering if maybe go didn't clean the value (garbage collected) since it wouldn't be used anymore and replaced this memory location with something else.

example output (with junk values removed):

```
created: 0xc2080006e0 40
2014/11/07 17:10:01  we got back: 0xc2080006e0 4921947622888946315
```

ANY pointer (hehe) is appreciated :)

Comment: It is getting GC'ed. You need to keep that pointer alive in Go so it doesn't.

Comment: @JimB also, Go's GC is allowed to move pointers around. Storing pointers on the C side is absolutely not safe.

Comment: @Jsor, technically true, but it doesn't yet. There's a lot of code that passes pointers to cgo, because it's the best we've got right now. This should be better defined go1.5. (In this case though there's no good reason for a pointer, copy the value in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go's garbage collector doesn't know about the pointers held by C or C++ code, so there is nothing to keep the `num` variable alive.

You can work around this by storing a second copy of the pointer in a Go variable.  One way is to use a global variable with a type like `map[*C.some_c_type]*int` or similar, and store `&num` there too.  Remember to protect the map with a mutex so things behave correctly when you have concurrent access.

In order not to leak, you will need to manually delete `&num` from the map when the underlying C code is no longer holding a reference to it.  If the C library provides the ability to set a destroy notify function when storing the user pointer, this will be easy: just export a Go function to C and use it as the notify function.  If it doesn't, but the Go binding knows when the the pointer will be finished with (e.g. if the `RigidBody` variable is always freed via the Go API, you can do the clean up there.